# How to sum by date

Tags: sql, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

How can I sum/group by date to show just 2 rows as sum i.e 1 row for 20200801 and result as 601749 which is the sum of 4 rows for 20200801.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY DATE

Row DATE    PRODUCT QTY
1   20200801    Product 1   7738
2   20200801    Product 2   549279
3   20200801    Product 3   32083
4   20200801    Product 4   18049
5   20200802    Product 3   31679
6   20200802    Product 4   4155
7   20200802    Product 1   7009
8   20200802    Product 2   10023
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Works fine, Is it possible to not lose the PRODUCT column, just showing a static value for each row as Prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`!

```
select date, sum(qty) sum_qty
from mytable
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Works fine, Is it possible to not lose the PRODUCT column, just showing a static value for each row as Prod?

Comment: @Sin: just add the literal value to the `select` clause: `select date, 'prod' as product, sum(qty) as sum_qty from ...`